# Package sun-java6-jre needs to be reinstalled

Tags: apt, software-installation, jre

I installed JRE 1.6u33, and there was a screen that came up asking me to accept the terms of service. I didn't know how, so I closed out of that screen without pressing Ok. Now, I can't install anything through the Software Center, or the Terminal. The Terminal gives an error message like this:

`E: The package sun-java6-jre needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.`

What are my options? Is there any way that i can re-open the window so I can accept the terms of service this time?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please remember to accept/upvote the best answer to your question (tick/check mark on the left). This way, the question is marked as "answered" and future readers can refer to it knowing the solution works. Thank you...:)

Answer (score 2):

Try this.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ferramroberto/java

sudo apt-get update
```

To install java JRE

```
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre sun-java6-jre-plugin
```

To install JDK

```
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk
```

Comment: This is my error log when I try to install the JRE...............................

cameron@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre sun-java6-jre-plugin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Type 'rramroberto/java/ubuntu' is not known on line 3 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ferramroberto-java-oneiric.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
E: The package sun-java6-jre needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.

Comment: Try `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ferramroberto-java-oneiric.list`

Comment: That got rid of the sources.list error. The error about sun-java6-jre is still there though. I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: I just did that and I think it worked! I'm going to try to install shutter. Let me test it! :D

Comment: That PPA is no longer really a good way to install Java 6, as it doesn't provide newer updates. (There are important security updates that have come out for Java 6 that it cannot provide because of Oracle's EULA change.) That PPA only provides up to [update 26](https://launchpad.net/~ferramroberto/+archive/java?field.series_filter=), whereas Oracle's Java 6 is currently at [update 33](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).